# Method has no context when passed to component's HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

In my component i got an object that holds reference to a function. But when i pass it to component's HTML and execute it doesn't have access to any other properties outside the function scope. Is there any way to make this work?

Here's my code:

```
button =  {label: 'My action', action: this.doStuff }
doStuff(){
if(this.userService.IsUserLoggedIn){ // Cannot read property 'IsUserLoggedIn' of undefined
//do stuff
}
}

<button (click)="button.action()">{{button.label}}</button>
```

I tried adding an additional function that binds `this` to function but I had no success.

```
<button (click)="exec(button.action)">{{button.label}}</button>

exec(func: Function){
func.bind(this);
func();
}
```

*sorry for any mistakes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have to bind the context when you declare your button object :

```
button = { label: 'My action', action: this.doStuff.bind(this) }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwzcro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

(I created `obj.condition` so that you can see a similar error when you remove the `.bind(this)`)

Comment: Indeed that was it. Thank you for the answer :)